# If ImageView drawable equals a known drawable

Tags: android

I have an imageview that has its imageresource set programatically. This image could have had its resource set by any of 3 drawables, which is chosen using various variables earlier in the class.
The 3 drawables are:

```
R.drawable.well_done
R.drawable.try_again
R.drawable.sorry_failed
```

When I click on this image, it could have any of these three drawables set to it, so I'm trying to run a method something along the lines of this (I know this is totally wrong, but it might help visualise what I'm trying to do)

```
public void game(){
    //STUFF
    if(result>10){
    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.well_done);}
    //MORE STUFF
}

public void results_page(){
    if(imgView=R.drawable.well_done){
        //DO STUFF
    }
    if(imgView=R.drawable.try_again){
        //DO STUFF
    }
    //etc...
}
```

Here is the proper code I have. Its a little more complex than my rubbish visualisation above, but I hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

```
    ImageView iv_i;
//...
...onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //...
    result1.setOnClickListener(onClL);
    result2.setOnClickListener(onClL);
}

private void game() {
    //...
    result1.setImageResource(R.drawable.well_done);
    result1.setTag(R.drawale.well_done)
    result2.setImageResource(R.drawable.try_again);
    result2.setTag(R.drawable.try_again);
    //...
}

private OnClickListener onClL = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.result1:
            ic_i = result1;
            iv_i.setTag(result1.getTag());

            break;
            case R.id.result2:
            iv_i = result2;
            ic_i.setTag(result2.getTag());
            break;

        }

        gotoResource();
    }
};


private void gotoResource(){
    Integer integer = (Integer) iv_i.getTag();
    switch(integer){
        case R.drawable.well_done:
        //STUFF
        break;
        case R.drawable.try_again:
        //STUFF
        break;
        case R.drawable.sorry:
        //STUFF
        break;
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get a nullpointerexception at the line containing `iv_i.setTag(result1.getTag());`

What did i go wrong? Or how do I go about doing this properly, or another way of doing it that would be easier? Maybe converting the drawable to a string, then doing an if statement for the string, like: (also know this is completely wrong, but its just for a visualisation)

```
String resource = imgView.getDrawable().toString();
if(resource.equals("R.drawable.well_done")){
//DO SOMETHING
}
```

Thanks

Comment: When do you initialize iv_i?

Comment: There a reason why you can't set the tag to something that contains an identifier? Or create a viewholder that contains your drawable and the identifier

Comment: @Sophicles its just declared at the top of the class by `ImageView iv_i;`

Comment: But it's null at that point.  Do you give it a value before you try to set its tag?

Comment: @Sophicles I did try the following: `iv_i = result1;` but that didn't work

Comment: Did you set iv_i to result1 *before* trying to set it's tag?  And what happened when you did that?
And do you ever link these to your activity (say with findViewById?)

Comment: yes, I set iv_i to result1 before trying to set the tag. I'm not sure what happened as the "//STUFF" in the gotoResource method never succeeded. (I was testing it with a toast notification, and the toast never appeared) but there were no crashes, nor errors in logcat.
result1 = (ImageView)findViewById... yes

Comment: @Sophicles I got the issue sorted, but thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying upon the exact drawable the ImageView has, I suggest setting a tag on the ImageView to indicate which state it's in. I recently used this approach on a similar issue (determining whether a button is active or not), and it works well for me.

```
private static enum MessageViewType { SUCCESS, TRY_AGAIN, FAILURE }

public void game(){
    //STUFF
    if (result > 10){
        imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.well_done);}
        imgView.setTag(R.id.image_view_status, MessageViewType.SUCCESS); // define image_view_status as a resource
    }
    //MORE STUFF
}

...

private void gotoResource(){
    MessageViewType messageType = (MessageViewType) iv_i.getTag(R.id.image_view_status);
    if (messageType == MessageViewType.SUCCESS) {
        //STUFF
    } else if (messageType == MessageViewType.TRY_AGAIN) {
        // STUFF
    } else if (messageType == MessageViewType.FAILURE) {
        //STUFF
    }
}
```

You can define the `image_view_status` id in any resource file. I personally use a file `res` > `values` > `activity_resources.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="image_view_status" type="id" />
</resources>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm having difficulty defining R.id.image_view_status as a resource. What do I do here?

Comment: I have a file `activity_resources.xml` in `res` > `values`, though you can use any `xml` resource file. In your case, the file would just have the item `<item name="image_view_status" type="id" />` in the `<resources>` tag.

Comment: ah right, I understand now, I have an ids.xml file for that sort of thing. I just wasn't 100% sure what you meant in your answer. Thanks! I'll try this now

Comment: I get the error "The qualified case label MainActivity2.MessageViewType.SUCCESS must be replaced with the unqualified enum constant SUCCESS"

Comment: Oh, `switch` statements don't naturally work on `enum` types. My mistake! I'll update my answer to use a normal `if` statement.

Comment: Brilliant! That's working great now, thank you very much! Marked as accepted